# How can I use enumset.contains in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, enums, enumset

I have an enum:

```
enum DestinationTab{
        Overview,
        ThingsTodo
    };
```

I set an enumSet in my action class based on certain conditions. On my jsp, I'd like to render only those sections which are present in this enumSet.

This construct doesn't work:

```
   <s:if test="eSet.contains('ThingsTodo')">
    print something
   </s:if>
```

How can I use enumSet.contains(..) in jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EnumSet contains Enumeration members, not strings.

To get an enumeration member, you can use valueOf :

```
<s:if test="eSet.contains(DestinationTab.valueOf('ThingsTodo'))">
 print something
</s:if>
```

Or, when the specific member to use is hardcoded :

```
<s:if test="eSet.contains(DestinationTab.ThingsTodo)">
 print something
</s:if>
```

Comment: I get an exception when I use the valueOF java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method valueOf. I think it can't interpret DestinationTab

Comment: Is DestinationTab visible and imported ?

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out, I was trying to use bit flags. A search pointed me to use EnumSet instead.

Comment: Its an inner enum within the action class. How/do I need to import it ?

Comment: Enumset work well for bit flags as they internally use a construct similar to ordinary bit vectors.

Comment: Yes, thats what I also gathered. I'm just struggling to use it within jsp :(

Comment: JSP don't always import internal classes implicitely. Add a specific import of `com.mypackagepath.Myclass.DestinationTab`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13714/discussion-between-brainydexter-and-dystroy)